# can we convert triangle wave to DC voltage? can i get any model circuit?

Tags: waveform

i've achieved converting square wave to DC by voltage doubler, where in case of triangle wave its hard to find solution to convert it into dc voltage

triangle wave form frequency is between 100khz to 1mhz

Comment: Please take the time to capitalise and punctuate properly. This is site policy. [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages. Please explain what your circuit specifications are and what transfer function required. e.g., Frequency, voltages, waveform shape, current / power for input and output.

Comment: A low pass filter, series RC. But you give no electrical specs in your question at all so can't answer it.

Comment: triangle wave form frequency is between 100khz to 1mhz @TonyM

Comment: You can use a bridge rectifier and capacitor on whatever you want.

Comment: You're not learning, Kevin. You have specified frequency between 100 kilohertz and 1 millihertz. You have also failed to specify voltage and current or load requirements.

Comment: kHz = kilohertz. MHz = megahertz. mHz = millihertz. "hz" is not shorthand for hertz. "Hz" is shorthand for hertz. Use a bridge rectifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can we convert triangle wave to DC voltage?

Yes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2finonm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]